# Checksum algorithm based on J.G. Fletcher

Tags: c, checksum

I have been tasked in implementing a Checksum algorithm that is based on the J.G. Fletcher checksum and ISO 8473-1:1998 and is described like so :

[image]

They then list 4 data that can be checked to see if the algo is correct but my version fails at the last two values.
0000 gives a checksum of FFFF
0000'00 gives a checksum of FFFF
ABCDEF'01 gives a checksum of 9CF8
1456'F89A'0001 gives a checksum of 24DC

I've been working on this for hours now and can't find what I did wrong, a new set of eyes could help tremendously.

Here is my function:

```
uint16 Crc_CalculateISOChecksum(uint8 *pt_start_address, uint32  length)
{
    uint8 C0, C1;
    uint8 data;
    uint32 i;
    uint8 ck1, ck2;

    /* Initial value */
    C0 = 0;
    C1 = 0;

    /* memories - 32bits wide*/
    for (i=0; i<length; i++)    /* nb_bytes has been verified */
    {
      data = pt_start_address[i];   
      C0 = (C0 + data)%255;
      C1 = (C1 + C0)%255;
    }
    /* Calculate the intermediate ISO checksum value */
    ck1 = (unsigned char)(255-((C0+C1)%255));
    ck2 =  (unsigned char)(C1%255);
    if (ck1 == 0)
    {
      ck1 = MASK_BYTE_LSB;
    }
    if (ck2 == 0)
    {
        ck2 = MASK_BYTE_LSB;
    }
    return ((((uint16)ck1)<<8) | ((uint16)ck2));    
}
```

Comment: You say something is wrong... Maybe you should also tell us why you think that, if you want help...

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is it? Or is the output wrong? How?

Comment: Sorry I guess it wasn't very clear what is my problem. In the problem description there is four data that were given to me along a checksum value they should generate (0x0000 = 0xFFFF; 0x000000 = 0xFFFF; 0xABCDEF01 = 0x9CF8; 0x1456'F89A'0001 = 0x24DC) When I try it with my function, only the first two data yield the expected checksum the other data doesn't give me the expect value

Comment: I ran my test again here is the values I get instead of the expected ones : 0xFFFF (ok), 0xFFFF (ok), 0xFFF2 (nok?!), 0xFFD5 (nok?!)

Comment: I was wondering if it was an endianess problem since we are working on a Big Endian processor but it is not the case :(

Comment: Did you ever fix this? And are those data given all in hex?

Comment: Pedantic: Fletcher checksum is **not** CRC.  You should not name your function `Crc_...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intermediate sums should be **uint16_t** (or uint16 in your lingo).

```
uint16_t C0, C1; // Not uint8_t.
```

Depending on what `char` and `int` on your system are (e.g. do not assume that int has more bits than char) your intermediate sums may be **overflowing**.  Your implementation relies on uint8_t being promoted.

To illustrate:

```
 0xFF               0xFF
+0xFF              +0xFF
=====              =====
0x1FE % 255 = 0     0xFE % 255 = 254
  ^Retain            ^Drop
```

Answer (score -2):

Just stumbled upon this. If someone is still interested: You iterate in the wrong direction.

Do NOT iterate from 0 to length-1 but from length-1 to 0, then it will work.

```
for (i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) // and change i to 'signed'
```

Comment: [**Fletcher**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum) checksum is **position-dependent**.  You must iterate from the first (index 0) to the last (index N-1) element.