# Does the complement have any impact on Fletcher's checksum?

Tags: c, checksum, twos-complement, ones-complement

The [Wikipedia article for Fletcher's checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum#Implementation) states:

> These examples assume two's complement arithmetic, as Fletcher's algorithm will be incorrect on one's complement machines.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8315215/335847) provides a scan from a book that says:

> Addition is performed modulo 255 (1's complement arithmetic)

Fletcher's checksum uses a running sum, so I don't see the need for negative numbers, and the aim is to identify differences, so as long as the same number system (one's complement, two's complement, neither) is used on the checking system then does it matter? The examples given on the Wikipedia page specify unsigned integer types too.

I've tagged this with C as the examples given on the Wikipedia page are all in C so perhaps that has some bearing in this. I'm not a mathematician and a barely competent programmer so it's quite possible there is some blindingly obvious reason why complement would have an impact.

Comment: It only matters in the sense that on modern two's complement hardware, or with unsigned computation, you're forced to manually account for the wrapping from 254 to 0 (modulo 255). A signed byte on a one's complement system would wrap for free, avoiding -0 or +0, without the need to manual intervention.

Comment: Oh, and imagine you were computing a simple arithmetic 8-bit checksum. If done directly in two's complement (modulo 256) then any single bit errors would only affect the more significant bits above them, whereas in a one's complement sum (modulo 255) avalanche around to the lower bits since the modulus is relatively prime to the bit positions. That is to say otherwise two errors in bit 7 would cancel each other out whereas it would take 256 errors to cancel an error in bit 0.

Comment: @doynax Thanks, that's helpful to know. I think you should add these as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The number system matters a lot.

Although Fletcher's checksum works using both two's complement arithmetic (integer computations modulo 256) and one's complement arithmetic (integer computations modulo 255), the resulting algorithms have different error-detection properties. The one's complement version has a minimum separation of undetected double bit errors of 2040 bits while the two's complement has a minimum separation of only 16 bits (table 1 in the paper).

Therefore, Fletcher explicitely recommends against using the two's complement version.